# Input Filter for moving to the correct project AND issue-type immediately via Jira Mail Handler via Subject Line

Tags: jira

Example
A Mail Handler. that reads the Subject and selects the correct project and issue type.
Subject: (PROJECT2)(Task) NewIssue
What I would like it to do. To find the PROJECT2 and create the NewIssue of type Task.
Is it possible for Jira to do it?
Thank you in advance
Luis Ribeiro

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the JIRA mail handler to have the Issue Key to get the correct Issue Key in the subject to get the correct project like this:

Subject: [JIRA] (JRA-#####)

This will get that project, you will have to set up the mail handler to set the project as a task (every email sent will be a task), the only way to get a specific type is to buy an additional add-on from JIRA for the mail-handler here:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue